# Combine enums c++

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

In my project, I have several enum declarations alike this one;

```
enum Comparison
{
    LT,     // "<"
    GT,     // ">"
    EQ,     // "=="
    LTEQ,   // "<="
    GTEQ,   // ">="
    NEQ     // "!="
};
enum Arithmetic
{
    ADD,    // "+"
    SUB,    // "-"
    MUL,    // "*"
    DIV,    // "/"
    MOD,    // "%"
};
```

And I'd like to combine several of these, into a single combined enum, such that;

- All elements (from the sub-enums) are present in the combined enum.
- All elements have a unique value (obviously).
- All elements have consistent value in the combined enum, and the original.

Like this:

```
enum Comparison
{
    LT,     // "<"
    GT,     // ">"
    EQ,     // "=="
    LTEQ,   // "<="
    GTEQ,   // ">="
    NEQ     // "!="

    ADD,    // "+"
    SUB,    // "-"
    MUL,    // "*"
    DIV,    // "/"
    MOD,    // "%"
};
```

Also what I'd like to be able to do, is to 'cast' the combined enum, to one of the original ones, given the value in the combined enum only (should be trivial assuming the values are consistent).

An alternative to enum, is a class based solution, where the classes implement the `operator int()` operator.

Note; I do believe the `operator int()` is somehow the way to go.

Comment: What happens when two elements have the same value in different `enum`s?

Comment: I'm not explicitly assigning values to any elements, I wanted the compiler to handle it automatically if possible. My current 'fix' is to simply assign the first element in each enum, to the value of the last element in the previous enum (+1). - However I don't find this pleasing at all.

Comment: Why do you wish to have several enums as well as a 'master' enum ?

Comment: Because the enums represent several logical entities, for instance; comparison operators, keywords, delimiters and such. - However for the lexer I need a unique id for each of element of these entities.

Comment: @Skeen:  If you don't explicitly set the values, the compiler isn't really setting it for you.  The default is to start at 0 and increment for each new enumeration element.  Setting them explicitly gives you the control you are asking for.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What I've commonly seen is this:

```
enum OperationType {
    Comparison = 0x100,
    Arithmetic = 0x200
};        

enum ComparisonType
{
    LT = Comparison,     // "<"
    GT,     // ">"
    EQ,     // "=="
    LTEQ,   // "<="
    GTEQ,   // ">="
    NEQ     // "!="
};
enum ArithmeticType
{
    ADD = Arithmetic,    // "+"
    SUB,    // "-"
    MUL,    // "*"
    DIV,    // "/"
    MOD,    // "%"
};
```

Which gives you a little more flexibility than simple chaining, because now you can add comparisons without disrupting your Arithmetics, and the Arithmetics and Comparisons don't need to know about eachother.  It also becomes trivial to get the type of an enum:

```
constexpr OperationType getOperationType(unsigned value)
{return static_cast<OperationType>(value&0xFF00);}
```

Comment: Are there any way to get the number of elements of an enum (on compile time)?

Comment: @Skeen No, you can't.

Comment: @Skeen:  With this method, yes, but not easily.  You would need to add a "Last###Element" enumeration to each of them, and then sum them up.  You could write a function to do that so anyone else who looks at the code won't scratch their head and curse you.  However, if that is the kind of functionality you are after, a large single enumeration is really what you want.

Comment: Can one assert that the enum values are unique? - without having a gazillion lines asserting each element against each other element? - My worries about this method is, if Comparison is expanded and grows into arithmetic, however adding asserts could ensure that this error would be caught on compiletime, whereafter you would change the operation type to add a little more spacing, for the new elements.

Comment: @Zac: Having the logical seperation will prove useful in the parser. So I'd rather stick with chaining if this shows up as my best alternative.

Comment: @Skeen: The intent is to make sure each category/type has enough space.  There is no way to prevent duplicates, even in a single enum.

Comment: @Skeen:  But you are not separating anything.  Enums, by definition, are just named integer constants.  You could leave the enum unnamed and simply have a long list of constants declared and be none the wiser.

Comment: Having a group of named integer constants is to me, prettier than having to comment all over my code to indicate that we're only using a given subset of the enums values. I am aware of the fact that non class enums do not provide any type safety.

Comment: @Skeen: The best I can think of is this:http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=1cd077d6f43379ce163f7d9d3b84eeb3-c96156d6cc95286981b0e9deef2eefae which I find _way_ uglier and more dangerous than chained enums.  On the downside, the values are no longer compile-time constants, so they can't be used in a switch anymore.

Comment: I do believe that your previous solution (the answer) is what I'll stick with.

Comment: I get a compile error with gcc 8.3 using c++17 >>main.cpp: In function ‘constexpr OperationType getOperationType(unsigned int)’:
main.cpp:46:72: error: invalid conversion from ‘unsigned int’ to ‘OperationType’ [-fpermissive]
 constexpr OperationType getOperationType(unsigned value) {return value & 0xFF00;}

Comment: @GrantRostig [Fixed](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/250875c8e71da622)

Comment: Zac Howland more or less provided this answer, but for clarity/simplicity: If you make the last element of an enum named something like "Size", then assuming you aren't doing your own arbitrary # assignment it will automatically provide the total # of elements in the enum.

Comment: Extending this to nested enums is obviously more difficult, but could be done by setting the first element to the prior chained enum's Size. This is achievable by wrapping each enum in a template struct that provides the prior enum: nextEnumStruct<priorEnumStruct::Enum>::Enum::First = EnumStruct::Enum::Last+1. (Pseudo-code - not intended to compile as written).

Answer (score 7):

A common (but not exceptionally elegant) way to chain `enum` together (for example if child classes need to extend a unique set) is to have each `enum` provide a "last" value and use it to start the next:

```
enum Comparison
{
    LT,     // "<"
    ...
    NEQ,    // "!="
    LastComparison
};

enum Logical
{
    AND = LastComparison,
    OR,
    ...
    LastLogical
};
```

Comment: This is what I'm using right now, and I'm looking for something a little more elegent ;)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately enums are not designed to be combined, so -unless implementing some factory-based ID generators, but this goes out from enums an compile-time solutions- you cannot do much more of what suggested by [Ben Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18344715/924727) or [Mooing Duck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18344942/924727).

Consider also that -by a language standpoint- enums are not required to be sequential, so there is no way to know how many of them are into an enum (and also makes few sense to know it, since their values can be anything), hence the compiler cannot provide any automatic  mechanism to chain (Jackson) or fork (Duck), hence it's only up to you to organize them. The above cired solutions are both valid, unless you are in the position you cannot define yourself the enumeral values (for example because you've got them from somebody else API).

In this last case, the only possibility is redefine yourself the combination (with other values) and map to the original through a conversion function.

Comment: I am in a position to change the enums. Also if enums are not required to be sequential then shouldn't I really set all's the values of the sub enums sequentially before using either of the suggested methods?

Comment: Yes, every enumeral (the constant into an enum) declared with no value has the previous plus one. You just need a starting point, or mark the ending point with a suitable name... but that's exactly what the suggested methods do. The point is that's you who have to take care they don't overlap. The compiler will do nothing against that.  And this is a scalability limit.

Answer (score 1):

## Fancy Template Version

Since there's no way to know the cardinality of an `enum` in C++ it is stuck with a fixed offset (here hardcoded as 100, but you could get template-fancy with that as well):

```
template <typename T0, typename REST>
struct enum_list : REST
{
    int base() { return 100 + REST::base(); }
    int unified(T0 value) { return int(value) + base(); }
    int separated(int value, T0 dummy) { return value - base(); }  // plus assertions?
    using REST::unified;
    using REST::separated;
};

template <typename T0>
struct enum_list<T0, void>
{
    int base() { return 0; }
    int unified(T0 value) { return int(value); }
    int separated(int value, T0 dummy) { return value; }
};

template <typename T0,        typename T1 = void, typename T2 = void, typename T3 = void,
          typename T4 = void, typename T5 = void, typename T6 = void, typename T7 = void>
struct make_enum_list {
    typedef enum_list<T0, typename make_enum_list<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7>::type> type;
};
template <>
struct make_enum_list<void,void,void,void> {
    typedef void type;
};
```

## Example

```
enum Foo { A, B, C };
enum Bar { D, E, F };

typedef make_enum_list<Foo, Bar>::type unifier;

template <typename E>
int unify(E value)
{
    unifier u;
    return u.unified(value);
}

template <typename E>
E separate(int value)
{
    unifier u;
    return static_cast<E>(u.separated(value, E()));
}

#include <iostream>
int
main()
{
    std::cout << unify(B) << std::endl;
    std::cout << unify(F) << std::endl;
    std::cout << separate<Foo>(101) << std::endl;
    std::cout << separate<Bar>(1) << std::endl;
}
```

Whenever you add a new `enum` you just add it to the list in `typedef make_enum_list<Foo, Bar>::type unifier`.

Comment: Interesting approach. Here's one with more variadics, static (why hope that the compiler will optimize all this needless instantiation away? Empty-base classes, ok, but the most-derived `enum_list` doesn't need to be instantiated either :)). Also, no need for `make_enum_list` if the base-offset is fixed at 100. See here: http://ideone.com/8lL0C3 Oh, and 10 LoC less :)

Answer (score 1):

Since an enum is really an int, you can wrap an int with a struct and use methods that cast to/from either enum type. Adding guards to the enums also helps with validating and converting back from an int.

```
enum OperationType {
    COMPARISON_OP = 0x100,
    ARITHMETIC_OP = 0x200
};

enum ComparisonType {
    UNKNOWN_COMPARISON = 0,
    LT = COMPARISON_OP,     // "<"
    GT,     // ">"
    EQ,     // "=="
    LTEQ,   // "<="
    GTEQ,   // ">="
    NEQ,    // "!="
    END_COMPARISON
};

enum ArithmeticType {
    UNKNOWN_ARITHMETIC = 0,
    ADD = ARITHMETIC_OP,    // "+"
    SUB,    // "-"
    MUL,    // "*"
    DIV,    // "/"
    MOD,    // "%"
    END_ARITHMETIC
};

struct Comparison {
    int value;

    Comparison(ComparisonType val) : value((int)val) { }
    Comparison(ArithmeticType val) : value((int)val) { }
    Comparison& operator=(ComparisonType val) {
        value = (int)val;
        return *this;
    }
    Comparison& operator=(ArithmeticType val) {
        value = (int)val;
        return *this;
    }

    ComparisonType get_comparison() const {
        if (value >= COMPARISON_OP && value < END_COMPARISON)
            return (ComparisonType)value;
        return UNKNOWN_COMPARISON;
    }
    ArithmeticType get_arithmetic() const {
        if (value >= ARITHMETIC_OP && value < END_ARITHMETIC)
            return (ArithmeticType)value;
        return UNKNOWN_ARITHMETIC;
    }
};
```

You can then compare the struct value with enum constants:

```
Comparison cmp = ADD;
switch (cmp.value) {
    case LT:
        ...
    case ADD:
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

About 'casting' the enums, I was thinking about a *discriminated union* of enums (sort of like Boost Variant but with (implicit) conversions and other conveniences specifically geared to enums. Without ado:

Assume we have two enums:

```
enum A { A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4 };
enum B { B_1, B_2, B_3, B_4 };
```

Note I donot concern myself about uniqueness of enum members, as I propose a *discriminated* union. Now, we'd like to be able to have a type `AorB` that behaves like so:

```
A a = A_3;
B b = B_1;

AorB any;

// any is isNil now
any = b; // makes it isB
any = a; // makes it isA

if (any == A_2) // comparison is fine, because any is in `isA` now
{
    std::cout << "Whoops, should be A_3, really\n"; // doesn't happen
}

if (any == B_2) // comparison
{
    std::cout << "Whoops, should not match"; // doesn't happen
}

a = static_cast<A>(any); // valid cast
b = static_cast<B>(any); // fails assertion
```

Here's my take on it:

```
#include <cassert> // for assert
#include <utility> // for std::swap

struct AorB
{
    enum Discriminant { isNil, isA, isB } discriminant;

    union
    {
        A valA;
        B valB;
    };

    AorB() : discriminant(isNil) {}

    A asA() const { assert(discriminant==isA); return valA; }
    B asB() const { assert(discriminant==isB); return valB; }

    explicit operator A() const { return asA(); }
    explicit operator B() const { return asB(); }

    /*explicit*/ AorB(A valA) : discriminant(isA), valA(valA) {}
    /*explicit*/ AorB(B valB) : discriminant(isB), valB(valB) {}

    friend void swap(AorB& a, AorB& b) {
        auto tmp = a; 
        a.discriminant = b.discriminant;
        a.safe_set(b.safe_get());

        b.discriminant = tmp.discriminant;
        b.safe_set(tmp.safe_get());
    }

    AorB& operator=(AorB implicit_conversion) {
        swap(implicit_conversion, *this);
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator==(AorB other) const {
        return 
            discriminant == other.discriminant && 
            safe_get()   == other.safe_get();
    }

  private:
    void safe_set(int val) {
        switch(discriminant) {
            case isA: valA = static_cast<A>(val); break;
            case isB: valB = static_cast<B>(val); break;
            case isNil: break;
        }
    }
    int safe_get() const {
        switch(discriminant) {
            case isA: return valA;
            case isB: return valB;
            case isNil: 
            default:  return 0;
        }
    }
};
```

See it **[live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=04e0094026943fe4b3964bdf572491bf-93e6c6235a92d0c233f44beab03470ad)**, printing:

```
main.cpp:20: B AorB::asB() const: Assertion `discriminant==isB' failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

So I've recently done something somewhat similar with the preprocessor, I know this answer is coming about 2 years late, but still.

Basically I have various non-contiguously defined enumerated types which I want to be able to extend from eachother so i have written the following preprocessor directives:

```
#define START_ENUM(name,extends)\
namespace name##_ns {\
enum name\
{ BASE = extends::LAST  + 1
#define DEF_ENUM(name) , name
#define END_ENUM(name) \
,LAST\
};};\
using namespace name##_ns;
```

The enums are created in their own namespaces to avoid multiple definitions of LAST and BASE. You could switch them out for enum classes if you don't like the namespace pollution, but it makes casting back and forth to unsigned ints way more of a hassle later on.

You need to define a base enumerator for successive enums to extend, but it can just be empty, depending on your preference for style

```
enum class base_action {BASE = 0, LAST = 0}
```

Subsequent enums can be declared with the directives

```
START_ENUM(comparison, base_enum)
DEF_ENUM(LT)
DEF_ENUM(GT)
...
END_ENUM(comparison)

START_ENUM(arithmetic, comparison)
DEF_ENUM(ADD)
...
END_ENUM(arithmetic)
```

It's just some syntactic sugar to create chained enums.

To combine all of these enums, you will probably still need to do some casting I use a simple struct to unify the enums

```
struct EnumValue
{
    EnumValue(unsigned int _val):myVal(_val){}

    //template method allows casting back to original enums and such
    template<typename T>
    T asBaseEnum()
    {
        //optional range checking
        return static_cast<T>(myVal);
    }

    //you could template these too if you want, or add 
    //a templated conversion operator instead 
    //(template<typename T> operator T()) 
    //but I personally don't bother
    operator=(unsigned int _val){myVal = _val}
    operator==(unsigned int _val){myVal == _val}

}
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by wanting to "cast the combined enum", but to allow for enum combinations, you use a bit-field:

```
enum Comparison
{
    LT = 0x0001,     // "<"
    GT = 0x0002,     // ">"
    EQ = 0x0004,     // "=="
    LTEQ = 0x0005,   // "<=" - combines LT and EQ
    GTEQ = 0x0006,   // ">=" - combines GT and EQ
    NEQ = 0x0008     // "!="
};
```

Since a few of them cannot be merged together (something cannot be both LT and GT, for example), you can adjust the bitfield to prevent that.

EDIT:

Since it appears you are looking for something slightly different:

If you want to merge enums, you can use the method Ben Jackson already described.  An alternative would be to do something like this:

```
enum Comparison
{
    LT,
    ...
    NEG
};

enum Logical
{
    AND,
    OR,
    ...
};

enum MyNewCombination
{
    LessThan = LT,
    ...
    NotEqual = NEG,
    And = AND,
    Or = OR,
    ...
};
```

This would effectively move all of your existing enums into the new `MyNewCombination` enum.  For the valid ranges, you could cast the `MyNewCombination` enum to a `Comparison` or `Logical` enum.

Comment: I'm not trying to merge these together as flags. I have several separate enums, that I'm interested in merging into a single one.

Comment: In that case, you either merge them into a single enum, or you chain them (Ben Jackson shows that below).

Comment: I was hoping for a third alternative, possibly using some cleaver templating, and the `operator int()`.

Comment: Without rewriting or adding stuff, you aren't going to get much more elegant, and overloading the casting operator not only wouldn't be elegant, it would reduce the readability of your code.

Comment: Will this technique ensure that the values in MyNewCombination are unique, wont the compiler assign values to the two sub-enums first, and then have issues on the third?

Comment: You won't be able to use the same names in your enum (hence the reason I renamed "LT" to "LessThan" in the combined enum, but there is nothing wrong with an enum having multiple constants with the same value.  In this particular case, context is likely going to determine which one you are going to use.  This is just mentioned as an alternative to chaining (since you've said you were looking for something else).

Comment: I can rewrite and add stuff, but I'd rather than not keep the logical separation of concepts and avoid the somewhat ugly chaining. As for the usage of the casting operator in this case, it is hidden inside the lexer.

Comment: One of my original requirements was that each element had a unique value in the combined enum.

Comment: If you can change/add, then why do you have multiple enums?  Just create 1 enumeration and be done with it?

Comment: Because I'd rather chain my enums, than I'll ruin logical seperation.

Comment: That was already mentioned as a solution (which you said you were looking for an alternative to).  But I don't think you quite understand how enums are defined.  There isn't really any "separation" with them.  They are effectively a shorthand way of writing `const int SOME_VALUE = 0;`  The fact that you put them in separate enum-brackets means next to nothing.

Comment: I was looking to see, if I could find a better alternative, yes, otherwise I'd just stick with what I've got. - I do understand that enums do not provide type safety or separation in any way enforced by the compiler, but I do believe most people will try to assign enums to the values inside of that enums declaration.

Comment: Also using enums is a way for me to logically group together concepts which belong together, which I prefer over raw integer constants and comments. - so while enums clearly means next to nothing compared to raw integer constant, I do believe they are more descriptive to human beings.

Comment: If they belong separate, then why are you trying to group them together?  You are making contradictory statements about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm trying to keep them separate for the parser, however the lexer needs them collected. - hence why I wanted to have a new union where they are collected for theleleast, only. (The lexer needs an enum containing all possible tokens)