# Is there a way to combine several enums into one?

Tags: c++

I have two enums:

```
enum class YellowFruits
{
    Banana,
    Lemon
};
enum class RedFruits
{
    Apple,
    Peach
};
```

I want to combine these two into one enum:

```
enum class Fruits
{
    //YellowFruits and RedFruits
};
```

So that it works like this:

```
enum class Fruits
{
    Banana,
    Lemon,
    Apple,
    Peach
};
```

But I can't find a way to do it.
When looking for a solution, I found this answer: [Combine enums c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344646/combine-enums-c/18344942). But the solutions in the answers there don't work for me. I want the new enum to work just as if I had created it with the values that it should take from other enums. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What do you want to happen when both enums have the same name?

Comment: Does removing the `}; enum class RedFruits {` lines with a text editor count as a way?

Comment: 1. This looks like a solution to a problem, but you did not say what the problem is. You are, probably, heading in the wrong direction. 2. Enums are just constant integers. Just assign the same values.

Comment: zdf is hitting on [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) There is no easy way to do what you want without a bunch of repetition, `enum`s don't do inheritance, so let's see if we can attack the problem that lead you to this difficult solution from a different direction.

Comment: `YellowFruits::Banana` and `RedFruits::Apple` have the value `0` and `YellowFruits::Lemon` and `RedFruits::Peach` have the value `1`. Unless you change one of them, making a combined `enum class` will not work (if you want them to have unique values).

Comment: What about this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18344715/14065

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not an `enum class`, but using C++20's [using enum declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Using-enum-declaration), you can make a `struct`/`class` that combines the enums under one name.  That would look like

```
enum class YellowFruits
{
    Banana,
    Lemon
};
enum class RedFruits
{
    Apple,
    Peach
};

struct Fruits
{
    using enum YellowFruits;
    using enum RedFruits;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(Fruits::Peach);
}
```

Which outputs `1` as seen in this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/41875118e6e75d6a)

Do note, Both `Fruits::Peach` and `Fruits::Lemon` will have the same value of `1` with this.  If you need each enumeration to have a unique value, then you can't use this.

Comment: You could do something like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18344715/14065 to make sure the ranges don't overlap.

Comment: I forgot about this question and just revisited it to find this brilliant answer, doing exactly what I was looking for. Enjoy an up-vote and the accepted answer-mark.

Comment: @JensB Thanks.  Glad to help.