# Plain enum to enum class

Tags: c++, enums, c++17

is it possible to perform some kind of casting to convert plain enum to enum class? E.g.

```
enum PlainEnum {
None = 0,
Foo,
Bar
}
```

Some converstion I'm looking for:

```
enum class ScopedEnum = some_cast<enum class>(PlainEnum);
```

Desired Output:

```
enum class ScopedEnum {
None = 0,
Foo,
Bar
};
```

I use a library where the enum is written in non-scoped style. I would like to use these library enum fields but in scoped style. I haven't found any asnwer on that question yet. Thank you for your time.

Comment: In a word, no. There's is no syntax to make a scoped enum from a plain enum. You would have to define the whole scoped enum in full, assigning its values individually as needed to match the plain enum

Comment: `namespace Xyz { using Enum = ::PlainEnum; using ::None; using ::Foo; using ::Bar }` then you can `int main() { Xyz::Enum x = Xyz::Foo; }`  (The global namespace is still "polluted" with the other identifiers.  And this doesn't provide the other affordances that `enum class` provides.)

Comment: You could use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68386145/4342498) technique

Comment: Both of those solutions will produce qualified names for the enum values, but not produce an actual scoped enum class.